# Adding native support prevents my library to build correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

This is a quite long story, but I'd really appreciate any help on this.

I am building an Android application using eclipse under windows. The application consists in one application (lets call it `App`) project and two library projects (let's call them `libA` and `libB`).

The `libB` project contains only java code (and android resources). It references the `libA` project which contains few java classes, lots of C++ classes and java wrappers for these native C++ classes generated using `Swig`.

In turn the `App` project references the `libB` project

I have managed to handle the swig part of the build within ndk-build by adding my own rules in the `Android.mk` makefile. And all of this was working good.

Lately I wanted to give a try to eclispse managed ndk-builds, this way I would no more have to manually trigger native builds through console.

So I've added "native support" to `libA` and (after just a little adaptation/configuration) it does build correctly the native `libA.so` file.

The issue is that ever since I've added native support to my library and updated eclispe's android plugins (ADT, CDT, NDK), it has become impossible to import `libA` in other projects. It seems the jar file is never created. And there is no option to "remove native support".

The error it's giving me in `libB` is:

`The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\path\to\libA\bin\libA.jar'`

And something similar in `App`, but one for each library:

`The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\path\to\libA\bin\libA.jar'`

`The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'D:\path\to\libB\bin\libB.jar'`

So I tried to go back, and revert everything related to native support in the projects. So, I have to call ndk-build manually through console (it works, the shared object is built). But the eclipse part still fails with the same errors. So I'm now suspecting the plugins update `v22.0.0.v201305140200--675183`.

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks.

** **EDIT #1** **

I've continued investigations, and managed to partially solve my issue by installing the Android SDK's build tools (separate package in SDK manager now).

The result is that I can now build my `App` project with ant in a console, but eclipse still can't. It seems like eclipse is trying to read `/path/to/libA/bin/libA.jar`, but what is created is `/path/to/libA/bin/classes.jar`

One new issue, when building the `App` project with on command line is that it doesn't import the shared library from `libA`.

Continuing investigations...

** **EDIT #2** **

I managed to fix the problem related to shared object not being imported. Created a `jni` folder with `Application.mk` and `Android.mk` in it. These makefiles serve the sole purpose of importing the lib, no source file there ( that's why I had no `*.mk` files there)

But eclipse + ADT 22.0.0 still can't build the project (searching for `libA.jar` and `libB.jar` instead of `classes.jar` in each location).

** **EDIT #3** **

I continued investigations, and I have removed everything related to eclipse in my project (i.e. `.externalToolBuilders`, `.project`, `.cproject`), re-imported them in my eclipse workspace. Now  the build system manages to import the jar library for `libA` and `libB`. But obviously it doesn't trigger ndk-build (since they are no more configured with native support).